# How do you clear the default attachment title from Wordpress 3.5 uploads?

Tags: image, wordpress, attachment, uploader, wordpress-3.5

I would like to clear the default "filename" from the image title when I upload a new image. I tried using the code below with no luck.

```
    add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_upload_title', 99 );
        function my_upload_title( $attachment_ID ) {
        $the_post = array();
        $the_post['ID'] = $attachment_ID;
        $the_post['post_title'] = '';
        wp_update_post( $the_post );    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first check [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/remove-title-attribute-from-images) and alternatively you can try the following code snippet too (paste the code in your `functions.php` file)

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'remove_image_text');
function remove_image_text( $attr ) {
    unset($attr['alt']);
    unset($attr['title']);
    return $attr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Shiekh Heera! Unfortunately both answers didn't seem to work in WP 3.5.

The funny thing is there's an "update_option" function for image align, link type and size.